# How to make a text or html tag look like a button

Tags: html, css, button

I want to show a p tag or legend tag or any html text like button. But how is it possible? I have tried with css but not working well.
I want to show it like button.

```
<p class="button" >Submit</p>
or 
 <a class="button" >Submit</a>
 or
<legend class="button" >Submit</legend>
```

[image]

Now need the button class.

Comment: It's not good practice to use anything besides an A element or a BUTTON element as a button. Here are some explanations why: http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/

Comment: thanks. Actually I want to call a JavaScript function when the fake button is clicked @Doug

Comment: A and BUTTON elements are keyboard accessible. Everything else is not. Hope 100% of your users use the mouse exclusively and never turn off Javascript.

Comment: Define “like button”. Then implement it in CSS. If you have specific questions about implementing a particular feature, describe the desired feature and show your best attempt at achieving it.

Comment: thanks. I had got the  answer from here . @JukkaK.Korpela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had just got what did I want.

**[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ydebmpwz/)**

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 1px #da7c0c;
    background: #478dad;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em; 
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .3em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.button:hover {
    background: #f47c20;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f88e11), to(#f06015));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f88e11,  #f06015);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f88e11', endColorstr='#f06015');
}
.button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: just FYI, you don't need:

`outline: none;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;` outline and text-decoration defaults won't do anything to a `p` tag and text-align: center would only be necessary if you were trying to center the actual button (not the text inside) in which case it would need to be placed on the parent, not the button.

Comment: Hmm, my one is complex and not easy to understand.I just share it. But got IDEA from your answer and from other place. Thanks.

Comment: yeah the rest is fine for what you are trying to do, leaving those lines won't do anything either way, it's just 3 less lines to include

Comment: Here is a good point .button:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
}
This made my text same to same like a button...

Answer (score 2):

Just apply css styles and `cursor: pointer;` to it to make it appear that it's a button

```
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: "arial-black";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;   
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oxz6fqfo/)

Comment: Thanks. I had got an solution but your one is easier to use and my one is complex and large code. Thanks very much. @jmore009

Comment: no problem. Happy to help. When you have a chance can you check this off so the question can be closed?

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

Here is the Working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kwjnrggf/1/)

**CSS**

```
  .button {
  width: 75px;
  background: #d2d2d2;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 32px; 
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button: hover{
  width: 75px;
  background: #0e567f;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You all are helpful to me. Just help.. I am going to my work now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple with css.

```
<p class='btn'> Button 1 </p>
```

And Your CSS

```
.btn{
float:left;
width:auto;
height:30px;
display:block;
border:1px solid #ff6600;
background:#00ff00;
color:#000;
line-height:30px;
text-align:center;
padding:0 20px;
border-radius:3px;
}

.btn:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ob67xnw4/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<p class='button'> Submit </p>

.button{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CCB5B6 20%, #274936 70%);
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 40px;
        color: #96F256;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 3px black;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .button:hover{
        color: white;
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this code and it is working well. You can change Color according to you.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jjt5um7m/1/)

**HTML Code:**

```
<input class="round-button-circle" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.round-button-circle {
width: 150px;
height:50px;
border-radius: 10px;
border:2px solid #cfdcec;
overflow:hidden;
font-weight: 15px;
background: #4679BD; 
box-shadow: 0 0 3px gold;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background:#30588e;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]