# Change format of textOutput in Shiny

Tags: format, shiny

I have a very simple shiny app. The user's enter a phrase, and the App extracts the last word and prints it.

```
require(shiny)
require(stringi)        
require(stringr)       

server <- function(input, output) {
        tokens <- reactive({
                token <- tolower(input$sentence)
                token <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", token)
                token <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", token)
        })

        output$lastOne <- renderPrint({
                word(tokens(), -1)
        })


}

ui <- navbarPage("Filter",
                 tabPanel("The App",
                          column(8, offset = 4,
                                 textInput(inputId = "sentence", label = "Enter your phrase"),
                                 submitButton("Filter")
                          ),

                          fluidRow(
                                  textOutput('lastOne')
                          )
                 ),

                 tabPanel("How to use")
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I change the format of the textOutput? For example, it should look like a button.

Comment: You can use `renderUI` to create a button dynamically with the textInput value. Alternatively, you can use CSS to make the text look like a button (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189587/how-to-make-a-text-or-html-tag-look-like-a-button)

Comment: Either I don't understand your solution, or I have expressed my self to vague. At the moment, the `textOutput` is shown as a normal text. But I want this text shown in a different format, like as if it is a button. Or some colored background or whatever.

Comment: I'll provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `renderUI`. You can also try CSS if you only want some color background. CSS can also make it look like a button but it's a bit tricky.

```
require(shiny)
require(stringi)        
require(stringr)       

server <- function(input, output) {
    tokens <- reactive({
        token <- tolower(input$sentence)
        token <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", token)
        token <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", token)
    })

    output$lastOne <- renderUI({
        tags$button(word(tokens(), -1))
    })

}

ui <- navbarPage("Filter",
                 tabPanel("The App",
                          column(8, offset = 4,
                                 textInput(inputId = "sentence", label = "Enter your phrase"),
                                 submitButton("Filter")
                          ),

                          fluidRow(
                              uiOutput("lastOne")
                          )
                 ),
                 tabPanel("How to use")
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```